# Python where is the definition/source code of FloorDivide in the compiler/parser?

Tags: python, parsing

I search for the code where FloorDiv or even Div, Add, Sub etc is defined but I don't have the definition like I want.

In Python/ast.c:

```
case DOUBLESLASH:
    return FloorDiv;
```

---

```
case '/':
        if (STR(n)[1] == '/')
            return FloorDiv;
        else
            return Div;
```

In Python/compile.c:

```
 case BINARY_FLOOR_DIVIDE:
    case BINARY_TRUE_DIVIDE:
        return -1;
    case INPLACE_FLOOR_DIVIDE:
    case INPLACE_TRUE_DIVIDE:
        return -1;
```

In Parser/Python.asdl:

```
operator = Add | Sub | Mult | MatMult | Div | Mod | Pow | LShift
             | RShift | BitOr | BitXor | BitAnd | FloorDiv
```

Grammar/Grammar:

```
arith_expr: term (('+'|'-') term)*
term: factor (('*'|'@'|'/'|'%'|'//') factor)*
```

http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2010/06/30/python-internals-adding-a-new-statement-to-python/ helped me to find theses places but not what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you're asking where in the CPython source code the actual floor division operation is defined? In that case, it's in the file [Objects/longobject.c](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.5/Objects/longobject.c#L3500):

```
static PyObject *
long_div(PyObject *a, PyObject *b)
{
    PyLongObject *div;

    CHECK_BINOP(a, b);
    if (l_divmod((PyLongObject*)a, (PyLongObject*)b, &div, NULL) < 0)
        div = NULL;
    return (PyObject *)div;
}
```

That function in turn calls `l_divmod()`, the definition of which you can also find in that file.

This is actually for the `int` type in Python 3, but the file is called `longobject.c` for historical reasons. Note that methods like  `__floordiv__` (`//`) are defined per class, so the above is only for integers. To find the code for floats, see `float_floor_div()` in `Objects/floatobject.c`.

Comment: Thanks ! It's the perfect answer !

Comment: Just an other little question, where Cpython concatenate strings

Comment: Looks like a combination of Objects/unicodeobject.c (PyUnicode_Append) and Python/ceval.c (unicode_concatenate). For whatever reason (probably performance), the unicode type doesn't define `__add__` or `__iadd__`, but these are explicitly handled in ceval instead.